# Having pages after specifying post_type post

Tags: posts, categories, pages, tags

I want to loop through all posts in category 4,but why is there still pages in the result after specifying post_type post?

```
$homeNeWs = new WP_Query(array(
       'post_type' => 'post',
       'posts_per_page' => 6,
       'cat' => 4
));
while ($homeNeWs->have_posts()) : $homeNeWs->the_post();

    <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>

<?php
endwhile;

wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

I did add a function to make pages have categories and tags,base on http://spicemailer.com/wordpress/add-categories-tags-pages-wordpress/

```
function taxo_for_page() {
  register_taxonomy_for_object_type('post_tag', 'page');
  register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'page');
}

add_action('init', 'taxo_for_page');

if (! is_admin()) {
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'cat_n_tag_archives');
}

function cat_n_tag_archives($wp_query) {
  $ary_one = array('post', 'page');
  if ($wp_query->get('category_name') || $wp_query->get('cat'))
    $wp_query->set('post_type', $ary_one);
  if ($wp_query->get('tag'))
    $wp_query->set( 'post_type', $ary_one );
}
```

Do i need to add more thing for the code above?

Comment: I believe this has been answered here. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16231132/wordpress-custom-search-page-returning-all-post-type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16231132/wordpress-custom-search-page-returning-all-post-type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `cat_n_tag_archives()` function is adding pages to all category and tag results indiscriminately. What you probably want (and I am guessing a little) is to restrict that filter to the main query only:

```
function cat_n_tag_archives($wp_query) {
  if (!$wp_query->is_main_query()) return; // This bit checks for the main query
  $ary_one = array('post', 'page');
  if ($wp_query->get('category_name') || $wp_query->get('cat'))
    $wp_query->set('post_type', $ary_one);
  if ($wp_query->get('tag'))
    $wp_query->set( 'post_type', $ary_one );
}
```